# heroku に webアプリをデプロイしたらView [welcome] not found.のエラーが解決できません

Tags: laravel, heroku

#### 前提

自身はUdemyでlaravelの基礎知識に関する動画を観ながら学習した知識程度です。
以前、投稿した内容のプロジェクトを一から作成し直した後の内容になります。

#### 解決したいこと

ローカルで動作確認ができているlaravelで作成したwebアプリをheroku環境でデプロイしたかったのですが、View [welcome] not found.(laravelのデフォルトのページwelcome.blade.phpが見つかりません)のエラー表示がされて解決することができません。原因や解決策が分かる方いらっしゃいますか。
[image: View [welcome] not found.]

#### 該当のエラーを解消するため実施した手順

(1)プロジェクト直下のProcfileの確認
[image: Procfile]

(2)ルーティングの確認
routes/web.php
[image: web.php]

(3)ルーティングで指定したwelcome.blade.phpのディレクトリ階層を確認
resources/views/welcome.blade.php
[image: welcome.blade.phpのディレクトリ階層]

(4)Composer.jsonの確認
一番下の行を追加し、ビルドスクリプトを実行する
[image: composer.json]

(5)各コマンドの実行

```
Composerの内容更新
Composer update

各キャッシュのクリア
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear

その後、デプロイメントコマンド実行
Git add .
Git commit -m “Initial commit”
Git push heroku master
```

### 補足

laravel:9.52.16
php:8.0.2

Comment: teratail で解決済みのようです。 https://teratail.com/questions/4vm4yntcp4of1x